# Stack Overflow/Exchange activity statistics?

Tags: support, statistics

Are there stats regarding the general activity on Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange? I would like to know, for example, at which time there is the lowest activity (Europe, India sleeping, evening in North America?).

Can I access stats like these somewhere?

Comment: I don't think you can access geolocation information like that, at least not publicly. Seems like it could be taken as a breach of privacy by some people

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm sure they wouldn't release the raw data, but [they have mentioned some aggregate stats on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-overflow-around-the-world/).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm not thinking of releasing the data to the public. I'm talking about nice graphs or (animated) graphics released by the StackExchange people - totally detached from personal information.

Comment: http://quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com & http://quantcast.com/stackexchange.com

Comment: @Yannis That's only for the US...

Comment: You can change it to global. Click the "more options" dropdown or the "traffic sources" dropdown next to the share button.

Answer (score 1):

http://stackexchange.com has some public traffic stats for all the sites in the SE network. However these are very general and will not show you a break down by time or location. That kind of detail is not made public.

There are third party sites that do some monitoring using external sources that you can use to get a general feel for things. Try [Quantcast](http://quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com) for one. Remember these guys don't have access to actual log files either, they rely on information gathered and extrapolated from various bandwidth providers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no page which shows the hourly breakdowns.

For active sites, such as Stack Overflow, you could look at the [chat activity](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) as a rough measurement of site activity.